# Wait for jquery confirm execution ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSF commandButton that calls onclick function to confirm the action. See:

```
 <h:commandButton actionListener="#{myMB.go}" onclick="return confirmYesOrNo('Remove Row','Are you sure ?')" />
```

The problem is my commandButton is clicked independent of result in confirmYesOrNo function. See:

```
function confirmYesOrNo(title, content, actionYes, actionNo) {
    var confirmReturn;
    if (!actionYes){
        actionYes = function(){
            return true;
        }
    }

    $.confirm({
        theme: themeDefault,
        title: title,
        content: content,
        buttons: {
            sim: {
                text: 'Sim',
                action: confirmReturn = actionYes,
            },
            nao: {
                text: 'Não',
                action: confirmReturn = actionNo
            }
        }
    });

    return confirmReturn;
}
```

AS you can see i'm trying to catch the return of button Yes(Sim) and Button No(não) to send as a return (`confirmReturn`). The problem is that variable `confirmReturn` returns before user can click in a option.

If i use normal confirm() everything works fine, the javascript waits for a option and return to onclick, but i need a more "pretty" component than default confirm().

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add for both buttons :

```
action: function () {
  return actionYes 
}

action: function () {
      return actionNo
}
```

and remove the return from below

Comment: I think it don't solve my problem because onclick is returned before action is called